# Realloc binary tree - how to update pointers

Tags: c, memory

For school assignment on linked lists I'm writing database of people which I have implemented by binary tree of this struct:

```
typedef struct TPeople {
    TPeople * m_Parent_1;
    TPeople * m_Parent_2;
   int m_ID;
   char * m_Name;
} TPEOPLE;
```

I create array with code:

```
int allocated = 20;
TPEOPLE * data = (TPEOPLE*) calloc(allocated, sizeof (TPEOPLE));
```

And realocate with:

```
allocated *= 2;
data = (TPEOPLE*) realloc(data, allocated * sizeof (TPEOPLE));
memset(data + allocated /2,0,allocated/2 * sizeof (TPEOPLE));
```

Because every person will be without child for some time i had stored them in array,otherwise I wouldn't find them again.

But there's comes problem as default size of array won't be enough to hold them all. But when I realloc the array, all those parent pointers are pointing in old location in already free'd memory.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks Rfilip

Comment: Can you please post your allocation and array declaration parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the right way to allocate binary tree nodes. Typically, each node is *independently* allocated: they don't need to be in physically contiguous memory because they have pointers to each other. Therefore, you do not need an array of them.

If you want to keep track of all of your nodes for the purposes of freeing them later, you can simply place the pointers to each node in a larger array of pointers-to-nodes, which you can `realloc` as you please.

Comment: I know, but as I said in question every person will be without child and without any pointer on it for some time. And array is way to keep pointers.

Comment: Allocate your children as they are created, and make sure to put them in an array when they are. (Or just do as my second paragraph states, and make a realloc'able array of pointers to nodes)